# Decimals showed by View

Tags: r

Is there any way to specify the number of decimals to be showed in a data frame displayed by View command? I don't see any options in the View method, so I guess it should be done using global options, the closest I see is options(digits=2), but it doesn't limit the decimals, but the digits.

Comment: If the data is all numeric, you can `round` the data as you pass it to `View`, eg `View(round(mtcars,2))`.

Comment: `View` calls `format.data.frame` that has an argument `digits`. The default uses the setting of `getOption("digits")`, so you can set this: `op <- options(digits = 2); [ code ]; options(op)`. This means save the original options, run code, reset `op`.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the options works for me, the data frame only has numerical data, but some of them are within lists. And options(digits=2) has a weird behaviour: it limits total number of digits, not just decimals